# PHP/MSSQL.. Select ID based on username, insert to table based on ID?

Tags: php, sql-server, database, select, insert

I have looked all over and at tons of code and examples.. This is such a small bit of code but I just can't seem to get it to work.

I have dbo.accounts which contains the id, username, password, createtime..

I have a simple form, you type in the username, and I need the select query to return the ID based on the username.

```
$result = mssql_query('SELECT id FROM dbo.account WHERE name = $username');
```

The dbo.gamemoney table will just insert some hardcoded info such as an amount of coins for the game..

My problem is that if I use a query as ID = 123, it works, but when I try to grab the id of dbo.accounts by using the username, I get nothing back.

I know it has to be something small, But I have tried to figure it out for so many hours now that I'm honestly lost..

Thanks for your time,
Chris

Comment: do you get any errors? also you need to put the $name inside quotes

Answer (score 1):

Since, `$username` is string type, you have to enclose it in quotes.

```
$result = mssql_query("SELECT id FROM dbo.account WHERE name = '$username'");
```

Comment: Thanks, The actual code did have the quotes, I created a test account with the username, cbunting. And used it in an example with the code above with quotes, $username = cbunting and that will display my info. But when I uses the submit form and post to the same page, I no longer get the id. Maybe my problem is how I'm posting the data. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As a better practice would suggest use a try-catch scenario so that you get the exact error log. Try -

```
$result = mssql_query('SELECT id FROM dbo.account WHERE name = "'.$username.'"') or die('MSSQL error: ' . mssql_get_last_message());
```

Comment: I did try that but get nothing either. Even though the replied code had quotes, I can pull the info if I use id = $id, but chars won't know that. But when the account name is put into the input field and submitted, Once the select trys to grab the ID based on the account name to submit to, `$query = "INSERT INTO dbo.gamemoney (userid,coins,creatime) VALUES ('$id',200,$creatime)";` this is when the id is blank. So the coins are never added to the account. So my problem still exists.. name = 'name' isn't returning the id for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help!

I was able to get it working. Now I'll make sure it's the right way. I had forgot to add,

```
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)) {
$id = $row['id'];
$ip = $row['ip'];
}
```

Thats why the id was blank. I was missing some code.
Chris